# Are there any side-effects on publishing at play store if I use the third-party security reinforce service on apk files？

Tags: android, security, google-play, apk

My Android Apk sometimes is cracked and decompiled.Then they change my app's package name and add ads or something else bad.I try to use some third-party security reinforce and encryption techniques to prevent being cracked and packaged twice. I want to know if it will have any side-effects on publishing an app in play store.

Answer (score 0):

The play store , **very recently**  now provides much more robust and tested code security features from play store. It is recommended to use that. Check the link below.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: 10x for the info but I don't quite understand the purpose of this new scheme. Does it protect your APK against republishing by a cracker?

Comment: It protects your apk from being hacked, All the details are available in the link.

Comment: Just try it out once and then try cracking the apk using many available cracking tools you will understand.

Comment: I also have read that but still don;t understand.What  you means is that apktool or other crack tool can't decompile and hack your apk?

Comment: @NirajSanghani Hi，I have used Google Play App Signing in one app.But I can't find any big difference.I still can crack it easily by decompiling it.I just find some modification in AndroidManifest.xml .Like this：```<meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" android:value="[ID]" />.```

Comment: Yes, it's no big difference.